# Finding the Absolute Maximum and Minimum of a 3D Function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Find the absolute maximum and minimum values of the function:

$$f(x,y)=2x^3+2xy^2-x-y^2$$

on the unit disk $D=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$.

Comment: Take partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ and set them both to zero.

Comment: I tried but at some point it did not work out.

Comment: See my answer below. If it's not enough I can give you the full solution, but it's better if you work it out on your own first.

Comment: It would be better if you give complete solution to compare it with my solution thank you

Comment: OK, working on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We first take the partial derivatives with respect to each variable and set them to zero:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=6x^2 + 2y^2 - 1=0$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=4xy - 2y=0$$

From the second equation, we have either: $y=0$ or $x=\frac{1}{2}$. Now we substitute each value into the first equation to get the corresponding variable: for $y=0$, we get $x=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$, while for $x=\frac{1}{2}$ we have no real solutions, so we discard this.

Note that both $(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}})$ and $(0,-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}})$ satisfy our constraint. We evaluate $f(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}})$ and $f(0,-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}})$ which give us $f=-0.27$ and $f=0.27$, respectively.

We now need to check the perimeter of the unit disk. On this disk, $y^2 = 1-x^2$, so we substitute this into the original function to get:

$$ f = x^2 + x - 1 $$

We set $df/dx=0$ to get $x=-\frac{1}{2}$, and we evaluate $f$ at this point to get $-\frac{5}{4}$.

Finally we have to check the extreme values of $x$ on the unit disk: $x=-1$ and $x=1$, which give us $f=-1$ and $f=1$, respectively.

You now have your global minimum and maximum.

Comment: I found $f = x^2+x-1$ when $y = 1-x^2$

Comment: Sorry, made a small mistake there. You still get $f=-5/4$ at the optimum though if I'm not mistaken again. :-)

Comment: @Pumpkin Do we agree now?

Comment: Yes, thank you for work :)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: for the interior of disk you may use usual condition $\nabla f(x,y) = 0$. For the boundary of the disk you may use parametrisation $x = \cos \phi$, $y = \sin \phi$ and minimize it w.r.t. to $\phi$ (remember, it's $2\pi$-periodic, so you should investigate it only on segment $\lbrack 0, 2\pi )$ really). Or you may use Lagrange multipliers method.