# Dimensions for the cheapest possible rectangular box

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

What are the dimensions for the cheapest possible rectangular box with a volume of 504 cm3  if the material for the bottom costs \$20/cm2, material for the sides costs \$6/cm2, and material for the top costs \$8/cm2 ?

I not sure how to use the information that I was given to solve this question. I know that I should use more 6 dollar pieces but I don't know how many of each I should use without doing guess and check.

Comment: What is the meaning of the $8 cm^2 ?$ with this question mark ?

Comment: Do you mean cube or rectangular box? Because the sides cost equally, thus, are all sides of equal area?

Comment: Let the three dimensions be $L$, $W$ and $H$. Write down the total cost as a function of those three variables. Use the known volume to eliminate one of the variables. Since you're taking multivariable calculus you should be able to finish the minimization problem.

Comment: you can use algebra to eliminate one of the variables and write the cost in terms of the other two. Then this question seems to take care of the rest: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/696529/265617

Answer (score -1):

For length $l$ cm, width $w$ cm and height $h$ cm, the material costs $c$ in dollars are
$c= 20lw+ 6(2lh+2wh)+ 8lw$ $=28lw + 12h(l+w)$
Note that the set volume of the box means that $h=504/lw$, so
$c=28lw + 6048(l+w)/lw$ $=28lw+6048/l + 6048/w$.

Then the partial derivatives on $l$ and $w$ are
$\frac{\delta c}{\delta l} = 28w-6048/l^2  $ and
$\frac{\delta c}{\delta w} = 28l-6048/w^2  $

Solving for zero derivative we get 
$l^2w = 216$ and $w^2l= 216 $

and thus $l=w$ at the minimum and we can solve for the dimensions.

---

*Initial answer*

It's relatively obvious that the top and bottom should be square, since we're looking to get minimum perimeter for the area.

So given that $s$ is the side length for the square base, the height $h(s)=504/s^2$ and the cost $c(s) = 20s^2+ 6\cdot 4sh(s)+ 8s^2$ $=  28s^2 + 12096/s$.

Then $\frac{dc}{ds} = 56s-12096/s^2$ and we can solve for the minimum at $\frac{dc}{ds} =0$.

Comment: So do I sub in 0 for both of them to find L,W, and H?

Comment: Well this it is not a square that we are looking at, it's a rectangle

Comment: @Joffan I don't think you can assume that $L=W$ is optimal because the price differs depending on the side. This makes some dimensions more desired than others because they are cheaper at achieving the same surface area than others.

Comment: Okay! So what should I do next to solve for the dimensions? I need to get it into l,w,h format.

Comment: you have $l^3=w^3=216$ so $ l=w=6$.

Comment: so then since it is out of 504 then h would be $72^3= 4.16$?

Comment: or should it be 14 since I should do  504/(L*W)=14

Comment: @Michelle , yes $14$.

Comment: @Michelle if you understand everything please upvote and accept, thanks.