# Finding absolute maximum and minimum in 3d function over a surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, surfaces

I need do find global max and min of
$$
z=x+y^2
$$
inside (or on the border of) the volume described by:
$$
x^2+y^2-25=0
$$

I've already found maximum values in $(\frac{1}{2}, +\frac{3\sqrt{11}}{2}, \frac{101}{4})$ and $(\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{3\sqrt{11}}{2}, \frac{101}{4})$ by writing the system of equations of the above ones, getting the derivative with respect to $z$ and finally finding the zeroes.

But I cannot find the minimum using some algebraic method$(-5, 0, -5)$.

I've seen from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/696529/1135081) answer that I should check the extreme values of $x$, but I do not understand the reason why, shouldn't these values be already included thanks to the system of equations?

(Do not use Lagrange multipliers nor Hessian matrix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the univariate case where you want to find the global extrema of some differentiable function $f(x)$ on some interval $x \in [a,b]$, would you not also calculate $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ to determine whether the extrema occur at the endpoints?

For instance, if I asked you for the global extrema (min and max) of $$f(x) = 2x^2 - 4x + 1$$ on the interval $x \in [-1,5]$, you would calculate
$$f'(x) = 4x - 4,$$
hence the point $x = 1$ is a critical point, and $f(1) = 2(1)^2 - 4(1) + 1 = -1$.  The second derivative is $$f''(1) = 4 > 0,$$ so $x = 1$ is a local minimum.  But now we must also calculate
$$f(-1) = 2(-1)^2 - 4(-1) + 1 = 7, \\
f(5) = 2(5^2) - 4(5) + 1 = 31.$$
And we see that $f(5)$ is the global maximum on this interval, even though neither $-1$ nor $5$ is a critical point.  For the same exact function $f$, it is also possible for the global extrema to be different than what we found above, if the interval on which the extrema are to be found is different than $[-1,5]$.

The same idea applies to your situation.  On the boundary, which is the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 25$, the function may have some global extremum for which the partial derivatives are not zero--i.e., it is not a critical point.  Conversely, there may also be a global extremum strictly *inside* the circle, but in this case, we know that if the function is smooth, then such an extremum will be a critical point.

Now that we have established this conceptual framework, consider how we can proceed.  We would search for critical points by noting that
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 1, \quad \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 2y,$$
hence there are no critical points inside the circle since the partial with respect to $x$ can never be zero.  Any global extremum must therefore be a boundary point.  In this case, the boundary is easily parametrized, which lets us reduce the question to differentiation of a single variable:

$$(x,y) = (5 \cos \theta, 5 \sin \theta)$$

is the polar representation of a point on the boundary $x^2 + y^2 = 25$, hence $$z = 5 \cos \theta + 25 \sin^2 \theta$$ on this boundary, and we can find the extrema in terms of the angle $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$.  Differentiating,
$$\frac{dz}{d\theta} = -5 \sin \theta + 50 \cos\theta \sin \theta = 5 \sin \theta (-1 + 10 \cos \theta).$$
So the critical points must satisfy
$$\sin \theta = 0 \quad \text{or} \quad \cos \theta = \frac{1}{10}.$$
In the first case, this implies $\theta \in \{0, \pi\}$, and in the second, $$\theta = \left\{\arccos \frac{1}{10}, 2\pi - \arccos \frac{1}{10} \right\}.$$
In terms of $(x,y)$ coordinates, these are
$$(x,y) \in \left\{(5,0), (-5,0), \left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3\sqrt{11}}{2}\right), \left(\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{3\sqrt{11}}{2}\right)\right\}.$$
The $z$-values are therefore
$$(x,y,z) \in \left\{(5,0,5), (-5,0,-5), \left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3\sqrt{11}}{2}, \frac{101}{4}\right), \left(\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{3\sqrt{11}}{2}, \frac{101}{4}\right)\right\}.$$
Since the $z$-coordinate of the latter two are greater than the first, we have shown that the global minimum is the second point $(-5,0,-5)$ and the global maxima are at the third and fourth points.

---

Alternatively, a more simple solution can be found in this specific case by observing that if $x^2 + y^2 \le 25$, then $$0 \le y^2 \le 25 - x^2,$$ hence
$$x \le z = x + y^2 \le 25 + x - x^2.$$
So the extrema of $z = x + y^2$ on the closed disk must also satisfy this inequality.  Since $x \in [-5,5]$, we see that when $x = -5$,
$$-5 \le z \le 25 + (-5) - (-5)^2 = -5,$$
meaning that $z = -5$ is the global minimum, since any other choice of $x$ will lead to $z$ being greater than $-5$.  As for the global maximum, we want to make $25 + x - x^2$ as large as possible, and this can be done by completing the square:
$$25 + x - x^2 = -(x^2 - x - 25) = -\left( (x - \tfrac{1}{2})^2 - \tfrac{1}{4} - 25 \right) = \tfrac{101}{4} - (x - \tfrac{1}{2})^2.$$
Since no real square is negative, the largest possible value is attained when $x - \frac{1}{2} = 0$, or $x = \frac{1}{2}$, which corresponds to $z \le \frac{101}{4}$.  All that is left is to check that this value is attainable for some choice of $y$:  when $x = \frac{1}{2}$, we have
$$y^2 \le 25 - x^2 = \frac{99}{4},$$
hence $y \in \pm \frac{3\sqrt{11}}{4}$, and $z = x+y^2 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{99}{4} = \frac{101}{4}$.  So we have found the global maxima this way as well.  Note this method has completely avoided the use of calculus.

Comment: But what's the reason why I can't also find the minimum using the system of equations and deriving with respect to $z$?

Comment: @albertopasqualetto Because it isn't a system of equations.  $z = x + y^2$ is the objective function--it represents the quantity that we want to minimize or maximize.  And $x^2 + y^2 \le 25$ is the constraint, and $x^2 + y^2 = 25$ is the boundary of that constraint.  They are not interchangeable, so they are not a system of equations.  The other answer is misleading because you first have to establish that there are no extrema *inside* the boundary before you can use that approach.  Finally, what do you mean by differentiating with respect to $z$?  That is like saying $\frac{df}{df}$.

Comment: yes, you are right, I meant differentiating z, so with respect to x and y. But I understood, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the boundary maxima/minima, this problem can be solved by tangency. The two surfaces

$$
\cases{
z = x + y^2\\ x^2+y^2=25
}
$$

are tangent at the maxima/minima. Eliminating $x$ in both we have

$$
(z-y^2)^2+y^2-25 = (y-y_0)^2(y^2+b y + c)
$$

due to tangency the double root at $y_0$ should prevail. This identity should be true to all $y$ so we obtain the conditions

$$
\cases{
z^2-c y_0^2-25=0\\ 2c y_0-b y_0^2=0\\
2by_0-c+1=0\\ 2y_0-b=0
}
$$

and solving for $\{z,b,c,y_0\}$ we obtain

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
z & b & c & y_0\\
 -5 & 0 & 11 & 0 \\
 5 & 0 & -9 & 0 \\
 \frac{101}{4} & -3 \sqrt{11} & \frac{99}{4} & -\frac{3 \sqrt{11}}{2} \\
 \frac{101}{4} & 3 \sqrt{11} & \frac{99}{4} & \frac{3 \sqrt{11}}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

NOTE

As can be depicted from the attached figure, the tangency substitution only works substituting $x$.

[image]